# Could not load assembly referenced by Directory.Build.props

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a Directory.Build.props with the following content:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference
                Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectName)' != 'X' And '$(MSBuildProjectName)' != 'Y' And '$(MSBuildProjectName)' != 'Logging'"
                Include="$(SolutionDir)\Libraries\Logging\Logging.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When i try to run a Console application that is inside the solution i get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Logging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

All IDE features works, like autocomplete and autofill usings.

If i manually add the reference like this it works:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Libraries\Logging\Logging.csproj"/>
```

and if use $(SolutionDir) it doesn't work:

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="$(SolutionDir)\Libraries\Logging\Logging.csproj"/>
```

Comment: Please move your solution into an answer - that will make it easier for other folks

Comment: WIll try to do that, thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(SolutionDir) is not a default MSBuild variable, but it is set by VisualStudio and Rider, so that's why it worked normally in the IDE but when it tried to run it could not find the Directory.

To fix this i basically create a SolutionDir variable like this:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SolutionDirectory>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory.TrimEnd('\\'))</SolutionDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Thanks for mtreit#6470 the help debugging this.